# Unable to generate default constructor while I've not declared that recently

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

As far I know, When we don't declare a constructor for a class, the compiler will declare a default one.

At the following code, I haven't declared any constructor for class "PencilCase" while compiler couldn't generate a default one...

```
#include <iostream>
enum COLOR {RED=1,BLACK,GREEN,BLUE};
class Pen
{
private:
    int color;
public:
    Pen(COLOR colr)
    {
        color=colr;
    }
    ~Pen(){}
    int GetPenColor() const
    {
        return color;
    }
};
class Pencil
{
private:
    int color;
public:
    void SetPencilColor(COLOR cor)
    {
        color=cor;
    }
    int GetPencilColor() const
    {
        return color;
    }
};
class PencilCase
{
private:
    Pen pen1,pen2,pen3;
    Pencil pencil1,pencil2,pencil3;
public:
    Pen GetPen1() const {return pen1;}
    Pen GetPen2() const {return pen2;}
    Pen GetPen3() const {return pen3;}
    void SetPen1(Pen pen) {pen1=pen;}
    void SetPen2(Pen pen) {pen2=pen;}
    void SetPen3(Pen pen) {pen3=pen;}
    Pencil GetPencil1() const {return pencil1;}
    Pencil GetPencil2() const {return pencil2;}
    Pencil GetPencil3() const {return pencil3;}
    void SetPencil1(Pencil pencilex){pencil1=pencilex;}
    void SetPencil2(Pencil pencilex){pencil2=pencilex;}
    void SetPencil3(Pencil pencilex){pencil3=pencilex;}
};
int main()
{
    Pen penfirst(RED);
    PencilCase myPencilCase;
    myPencilCase.SetPen1(penfirst);
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to declare a constructor for "PencilCase" on my own
But I received following error:

"Cannot find default constructor to initialize"

My main question is that Why the compiler says it couldn't declare a default constructor while I've not declared a constructor? And am I forced to declare a constructor for the class "PencilCase" on my own? If your answer is yes, why?

Comment: A default constructor cannot be implicitly defined because `PencilCase` has members that can't be default-initialized. In other words, the compiler doesn't know how to construct `pen1` et al - they require an argument.

Comment: Instead you should know that "when we don't declare a constructor for a class, the compiler will define a default one **if it is possible to do so**".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you mean that If I declare a constructor for a child class (e.g. pen) I should declare a constructor for parent class (PencilCase) too?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terms "child class" and "parent class". In this example, since an instance of `Pen` cannot be default-constructed (you cannot write `Pen mypen;`), so naturally the compiler is unable to generate a default constructor for `PencilCase`, since that constructor would be responsible for constructing `pen1`, `pen2` and `pen3`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I got it. thanks a lot :)